# Error using SPRequest when the SPWeb is already disposed

Tags: 2010, list, development, spweb

Is this correct way of using the SPSite and SPWeb and the SPList.

```
private SPList list;

pulic void getList()
{
using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0])
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
        list = lists.TryGetList("listname");
    }
} 
}

private override void PerformAction()
{
  //retrieving items from the splist
}
```

I think because of this code i get an error:

> Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.   Please
>   close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from
>   them, but not before.   Stack trace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()  ....

Can the cause be: that i retrieve list and then so to say dispose the SPWeb object as im using it in using clause, but the list instance is still there and i try to retrieve items from it? I do NOT perform any insert or update actions only retrieve.

And if it is the cause how can i work around that? The retrievement of the list should happen in different method, because i do an override of the method.

I transformed the code to this, as msdn says rootweb I shouldn't dispose.

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
    list = lists.TryGetList("listname");
}
```

Still have the same error in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to work with SharePoint, first at all, you should read [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It describes how to dispose SharePoint objects.

In the post you can find this:

```
public void RootWebBestPractice()
{
    // New SPSite.
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://moss"))
    {
        SPWeb rootWeb1 = siteCollection.RootWeb;
        // No explicit rootWeb1 dispose required.
    }  // siteCollection automatically disposed by implementing using().
    // rootWeb1 will be Disposed by SPSite.

    // SPContext and SPControl
    SPWeb rootWeb2 = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
    // Also would apply to SPControl.GetContextSite(Context);
    // No explicit rootWeb2 dispose required because it's obtained from SPContext.Current.Site.
}
```

Comment: I did read this posts many times ... but i still get this error and im disposing the object right, I'm always using the best practice in this case the "using" clause. Which automatically disposes the objects when they are out of the context

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Also I suggest you to work with list items in the same context that you use to retrieve a list.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it like this:

```
 SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
 SPList mySPList = currentSite.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("VoorbeeldLijst");

 if (mySPList != null)
 {
   ...
   ...
 }
```